# How to append an element to HList

Tags: scala, shapeless

I'm experimenting with the following class

```
import shapeless._
import syntax.std.tuple._

class TestedClass[HL](nodes: HL) {

    def addElement[T, OUT](clause: HL => T) = {
        new TestedClass[OUT](nodes :+ clause(nodes))
    }
}
```

Obviously this fragment doesn't compile. I don't know how to bind the new tuple `nodes :+ clause(nodes)` type to OUT. What I would like to achieve is the following:

```
scala> val step1 = new TestedClass[(Int)](1)
res1: TestedClass[(Int)]

scala> val step2 = step1.addElement(nodes => 2.0)
res1: TestedClass[(Int, Double)]
```

Is it possible with Scala?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, although not quite so nicely, since Scala doesn't provide syntax for `Tuple1`. But the following will work:

```
import shapeless._, ops.tuple.Prepend

class TestedClass[HL](nodes: HL) {
  def addElement[T, OUT](clause: HL => T)
    (implicit prepend: Prepend.Aux[HL, Tuple1[T], OUT]) = {
      new TestedClass[OUT](prepend(nodes, Tuple1(clause(nodes))))
    }
}
```

And then:

```
scala> val step1 = new TestedClass[Tuple1[Int]](Tuple1(1))
step1: TestedClass[(Int,)] = TestedClass@4fb78b02

scala> val step2 = step1.addElement(nodes => 2.0)
step2: TestedClass[(Int, Double)] = TestedClass@20406333
```

The basic trick whenever you want to use an operation from Shapeless is to find the type class you need and require the appropriate instance as an implicit parameter. In this case the `Prepend` for tuples is what we want.

Comment: Thank you @TravisBrown, you rock!
Unfortunately Idea is not so great.  
  
  `val step1 = new TestedClass[Tuple1[Int]](Tuple1(1))`  
  `val step2 = step1.addElement(nodes => 2.0)`  
  `val step3 = step2.addElement { case (node1, node2) => "test"`  
  
  In step3 Idea doesn't recognize types of node1 and node2.  

I will raise a bug to Idea team I guess

Answer (score 0):

You can append another HList to an HList:

```
class TestedClass[A <: HList](nodes: A) {

  def addElement[B, C](clause: A => B) = {
    new TestedClass(nodes :: (clause(nodes) :: HNil))
  }

  // def split[H, T <: HList](l: H :: T) = (l.head, l.tail)
}
```

Comment: Even apart from the fact that this is working explicitly with `HList` instead of tuples, it doesn't really do what the OP wants at all—you're not adding an element to the end of `nodes`, you're creating a new `HList` with `nodes` as the first element and the output of `clause` as the second.